# getting route name not the route path in twig symfony

Tags: twig, symfony, router

i'm developing an application with symfony3.
I want to get route name in twig. i did this :

```
 {% set current_path = path(app.request.get('_route')) %}
 {{ current_path }}
```

it displays the url of the current page. But i want to get route name not the path.
example :

```
personnel_index:
    path:     /liste
    defaults: { _controller: "PersonnelBundle:Personnel:index" }
    methods:  GET
```

must return : personnel_index

> so how can i get the route name

Comment: $request->attributes->get('_route'); works so try app.request.attributes.get('_route'); and see what happens.

Comment: thanks for relying but it diplays always the path

Comment: Drop the path function.  set current_route_name = app.request.attributes.get('_route')

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This is because you put the path function try like this

```
{% set current_path = app.request.get('_route') %}
{{ current_path }}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the twig template, there is a global variable `activeRoute`.

For example  `{{ dump(activeRoute) }}` will give you the route name.

There is one example at `vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/views/storefront/component/address/address-personal.html.twig:40`

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/component/address/address-personal.html.twig#L40)

With this source code.

```
{% if activeRoute == 'frontend.account.login.page' %}
   {% set isLoginPage = true %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That is not something that is provided by Symfony. The accepted answer works.

Comment: You are very right, my comment is all about the activeRoute variable which is equivalent to app.request.get('_route') and how it has been used in Shopware core. @hattila